# What is the meaning of "array type has incomplete element type"?

Tags: c, hashtable, glib, gcc4

I have the following simple lines of code:

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void my_func () {
    GHashTable htbls[3]; /* ASSUME LINE NUMBER IS N */
    /* Do something */
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    my_func ();
    return 0;
}
```

But

```
$gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` ./main.c
```

gives the following error:

```
./main.c:N: error: array type has incomplete element type
```

I don't understand why the element type is incomplete.  `GHashTable` is completely specified in `glib.h`.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It presumably means that `GHashTable` is not completely defined in the headers you include.  That is, there is likely a line in `glib.h` or one of the files it includes that reads something like:

```
typedef struct GHashTable GHashTable;
```

The structure tag could be different without changing my argument.  There must be something similar because otherwise you'd get a different message about `GHashTable` not being recognized as a type name:

```
error: unknown type name 'GHashTable'
```

There is no extra information provided about the structure in `<glib.h>`; you don't need to know it to use it.  The API for the hash table functions probably deal with `GHashTable *` values only, so you don't need to know what's inside, any more than you need to know what's inside a `FILE *` to be able to use it in your code (though macroized functions such as `getchar()` might need to know about the internals of `FILE *`; maybe a better analogy is `DIR *`, but that's a POSIX interface and not necessarily as well known).

It means you will need to use:

```
 GHashTable *htbls[3];
```

You can have arrays of pointers to incomplete types without problem.

Comment: Yeah, it's defined as: `typedef struct _GHashTable  GHashTable;` (`glib/ghash.h` for glib2, `glib.h` for glib1), without `_GHashTable` being defined.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure about that? Copy/paste the specification from glib.h. (My glib.h does not contain a definition for GHashTable).

You need to use a pointer, not a value:

```
GHashTable* htbls[3];
```

Answer (score 5):

Q: Isn't GHashTable is completely specified in glib.h?

A: No.

If you want a hashtable, you should use g_hash_table_new(), g_hash_table_add () and friends:

- http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html

In other words, "struct _GHashTable" is opaque to your application.

If you really want an array of GHashTables, then you'll need an array of "GHashTable *".  And you'll need to explicitly initialize each element of your array with its own, new hash table.